# Load a saved model on Pytorch AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I trained a model, and I saved the best one, with:

```
# Store params at the best validation accuracy
if save_param and accuracy_star > best_accuracy:
    torch.save({'vgg_a':nets[0].state_dict(),'classifier':nets[3].state_dict()}, f"{model_name}_best_test.pth")
```

So, at the end of the training I downloaded this "federated_mnist_best_test.pth" on my local computer.
Now, I created a new notebook on google colab, and I tried din this way to upload the model:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Inside uploaded I put my .pth file, and then:

```
state_dict = torch.load(uploaded)
```

gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having called `uploaded = files.upload()` (usage examples can be found on [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c)) and interacted with the file explorer, the file will be uploaded to google Colaboratory's temporary file system.

You can find it by looking at the side panel:

[image]

At this point, the file has been uploaded to the file system but hasn't yet been loaded on the notebook. You need to load the file using its name (*e.g.* if the name is `best_test.pth`):

```
state_dict = torch.load('best_test.pth')
```

Comment: I do not know if I have to create another question, however, inside my .pth file I had 2 models, called classifier and vgga. If I load state_dict, it loads both of them, but I want to create two models, called classifier_new and vgga_new with the weights coming from this state_dict. How can I do?

Comment: Sure: the object returned by `torch.load` is essentially the same as the one you passed to `torch.save`. In your case it will be a dict containing the two model state dicts. To access them simply do `state_dict['classifier']`, you can load it onto your `nn.Module` with `classifier.load_state_dict(state_dict['classifier'])` (same goes for the other one with `state_dict['vgg_a']`).

Answer (score 1):

The return of `.upload()` is a dictionary (see [docs](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/f31c2c03993b733b8f5ae7c7a451077f72ca6882/google/colab/files.py#L43-L44)).

Here's three ways to fix your problem (I recommend the 2nd solution):

1. If you know that only one file was uploaded, but you don't know its name:

   ```py
   state_dict = torch.load(next(iter(uploaded.keys())))
   ```

   You can add some checks, if you will, e.g.:

   ```py
   if len(uploaded.keys()) > 1:
       raise Exception('More than one files were uploaded.')

   state_dict = torch.load(next(iter(uploaded.keys())))
   ```

   **This method has one problem**: if you try to upload the same file again (or some other file with the same filename, for some reason), there will be a conflict of filenames and Google Colab will rename it locally (adding  `(1)`, for instance). The problem is that the `.keys()` always refer to the original filename, which won't be the file you want. To avoid that problem, see next solution.
2. If you only uploaded one file, and cannot ensure the filename will be unique:

   ```py
   import io
   state_dict = torch.load(io.BytesIO(next(iter(uploaded.values()))))
   ```

   You can perform the same check as we did in the previous solution.
3. If you know the name of the file that you want to load:

   Proceed as suggested in [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864295/4228275).

Comment: Thank you! I voted Ivan's answer only because he answered before, but both are correct

Comment: I do not know if I have to create another question, however, inside my .pth file I had 2 models, called classifier and vgga. If I load state_dict, it loads both of them, but I want to create two models, called classifier_new and vgga_new with the weights coming from this state_dict. How can I do?

Comment: @CasellaJr no problem, if your use-case was the third, you did right. The answer to the other question can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_multiple_models_in_one_file.html).

Comment: In general you should accept the answer you find most useful, not the one which was posted first. This is not to tell you to vote one way or the other here, just an FYI.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but the two answers both solved the problem. @WaiHaLee